# Does group { } finish before control passes to next block command in chain?

Tags: gatling

I have a Gatling (1.5.5) scenario that looks something like this:

```
.group( "name" ) {
  // do a sequence of things that are a logical flow (in this case, log in)
  .exitHereIfFailed
}
.feed( source )
.exec( session => println( some.value.in.session ) )
.group( "next step" ) { ... }
```

What I expected was, if the login failed, it would not continue.  There would be no output.

What I actually saw when the login failed was, the feed was being consulted, the data was being populated into the session, and it was being output, but the following group was not being executed.

What is really going on?  are the feed() and exec( func ) elements executing in parallel while the first group is executing?  Or do those two not honor the .exitHereIfFailed and get executed anyway?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bug, but it was probably fixed in Gatling 2.

Comment: I will confirm when I have time to get up to speed on Gatling 2.  Thanks!